# random number counter not working

Tags: java

This is a program to throw a dice n number of times and show the frequency and probability of getting each side...........

```
 import java.util.*;
class apples{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int freq[]=new int [6];

    System.out.println("How many times do you want to roll the dice");
    int n=input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("turn\tface");
    for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++){
        int num=1+rand.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println(i+"\t"+num);
    ++freq[num-1];
    }

    System.out.println("face\tfrequency\tprobabitity");
    for(int i=0;i<freq.length;i++){
        float p=freq[i]/n;
        System.out.println((i+1)+"\t"+freq[i]+"\t\t"+p);
    }


}
```

}

after running the program I  get the probability of each dice face as 0.Please help me sort it out.

Comment: Hint: Division of integers and rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction:

```
  float p=(float)freq[i]/n;
```

You have to cast one of the operators to `float`.

So it could be the second operator as well like this:

```
float p=freq[i]/(float)n;
```

[Here's an explanation from JLS:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)

> Integer division rounds toward 0.

Answer (score 1):

To explain that: You are dividing one integer (freq[i]) by another integer (n). The result will, again, be an integer (and thus, everything after the decimal point is lost). Casting that to float will be to late (as the number is already exactly zero). You have to make sure that you divide one float by an integer, then your result will also be a float (and correct).

Answer (score 0):

this will be help to you or not inform me
`float p = ((float)freq[i])/n`

If you want to get floating point value you have to divide float by int . So in this case you have to cast your freq[i] value. it will make the results better